# Oracle DB getting same sequences across different Environments?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a Schemas in Oracle which has Lot of linked Schemas as well,

I have four basic environments Dev/Prod/INT/UAT.

I want to have a mechanism via which the Sequence generation on all four env gives me the same value when doing inserts in the Prod SCHEMA for individual schema .

e.g Say Table A has Id column being generated by a Oracle Sequence generator, I want the exact same values to be generated on all my other Oracle DB instances across Dev/UAT/INT as PROD.

Reason why i need this,

I  do a lot of Prod to UAT/Dev/INT dumps for various linked schema's and without having the same sequences the data is not good enough for analytics as **I donot want to do a Parent Schema Dump againa and again**

Any details on the same helps

thnx

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question.  What does it mean to have "child schemas under" a parent schema?  I'm guessing that just means that you have multiple schemas, that may have some cross-schema foreign keys.  I don't understand the behavior you are trying to achieve.  Do you want to ensure that the nth row inserted in dev gets the same sequence value as the nth row inserted in prod?  Do you want to ensure that inserts done at the same moment in dev and prod get the same sequence value?  I don't understand what doing a "parent schema dump" accomplishes or how sequences are involved.

Comment: So if you insert 1000 rows in prod, but only 2 in dev, which values should the dev sequence generate? 1 and 2? 999 and 1000? 42 and 81?

Comment: I donot want to do a full DB to DB dump for all schemas; you're right probably parent child was not the correct terms to use here, I want the Cross schema foreign keys to still work

Answer (score 1):

If you are using only one sequence on one DB, that is called from different DBs, everytime you call "nextval" it will count +1. If you can't execute all of the commands in one session, this cant be done using sequences. You can create your own and handle (increase) them as you like.

Answer (score 1):

This is not what a sequence is intended to do.  If you insert the same rows in the same order on your various instances, then they should wind up with the same sequence values, but this is not something you want to rely on.  If you want to be able to compare data across multiple instances, you should do your comparison based on a natural key (i.e., the data itself) instead of a synthetic one (the sequence).